# Manipulating character entities with XSL and string-to-codepoint

Tags: xslt, character-encoding

I'm relatively new to XSL. I need to handle special characters (anything outside of the BasicLatin code block) in a particular manner. I understand that entity codes and literal characters are basically identical, but I have a need to work in a text editor that doesn't see it that way (and that is out of my control). So keeping the literal characters isn't an option. I'd like to handle this in my XSL rather than through Perl or some other mechanism, if that's possible. Here's what I have:

```
<p>This is a story&#x2014;a long story.</p>
```

This is my desired result:

```
<p>This is a story<0x2014>a long story.</p>
```

I've been trying to do this via regular expression, something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(\P{IsBasicLatin})', 'concat('&lt;0x', string-to-codepoints($1), '&gt;'))"/>
```

But I get an error that a separator is needed after a numeric literal. I haven't been able to find any documentation of that error that I understand. Is it related to my attempt to use functions as part of the replacement? Is such a thing allowed in XSL? If not, any suggestions would be welcome. I did review the answers provided here: [convert character if codepoint within given range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798974/convert-character-if-codepoint-within-given-range), which seemed relevant but didn't work for me (the first wipes out my special characters, the second gives me very odd output.)

Any help would be appreciated. I assume I'm missing something about either functions or codepoints, but I've hit a bit of a wall on my own. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's kosher to answer my own question, but I did finally figure out a partial solution which is similar to the first answer at the link I gave.
`<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\P{{IsBasicLatin}}">`
`<xsl:matching-substring>`
`<xsl:text>&lt;0x</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="string-to-codepoints(regex-group(0))"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>`
`</xsl:matching-substring>`
`<xsl:non-matching-substring>`
`<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`
`</xsl:non-matching-substring>`
`</xsl:analyze-string>`

Answer (score 1):

The output you are trying to produce is not well-formed XML, so XSLT is reluctant to allow you to produce it. Are you sure you want to produce output that no XML parser will accept?

The actual problem in your code is the single-quotes around the call to concat. The expression you have written is the string literal 'concat(' followed by the operator <, followed by the integer literal zero, followed by the name x, and this is not valid XPath syntax.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. That doesn't seem to fix the larger issue, which, as far as I can tell, has to do with $1 being read as a numeric-literal and therefore failing as an argument of string-to-codepoints (this is my best guess at a description of the problem). I've tried string-to-codepoints(string($0)), still to no avail.

However, I did work out a partial solution with analyze-string and regex-group, only to discover that string-to-codepoints outputs decimal codes instead of hex! But it's something.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if it's kosher to answer my own question, but I did finally figure out a partial solution which is similar to the first answer at the link I gave.

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\P{{IsBasicLatin}}"> 
  <xsl:matching-substring> 
    <xsl:text>&lt;0x</xsl:text>

    <xsl:value-of select="string-to-codepoints(regex-group(0))"/>

    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:matching-substring> 
  <xsl:non-matching-substring> 

    <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
  </xsl:non-matching-substring> 
</xsl:analyze-string>
```